# How to use highcharts with angular 5?

Tags: highcharts, angular

Is there any way to use highcharts.js with angular2 ?Is there any option available instead of highcharts?

Comment: https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-highcharts-with-angular-5-6c6564a55cf0

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could also try [angular2-highcharts](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts) I implemented.

Comment: Do you have any examples of using angular2-highcharts with a pie chart? Thanks

Comment: it is just a wrapper for Highcharts. take any example from the readme and change highcharts config

Comment: I tried the spline example on plunker to create a gauge chart. http://plnkr.co/edit/OQSFSKisIIWAH0megy4d?p=preview. Did not work. The error was that I need highcharts-more.js. Do I have to reference highcharts-more somewhere?

Comment: im also unable to use the highchrts-more with angular-cli @user2347528 did you have any luck?

Comment: Is it Open Source ? Can i Use to for my Client ? he is for sure going to use the application for commercial purpose !

Comment: How do I create a highchart type object, so that I can call .reflow() method?

Comment: It seems you're not maintaining this repo anymore no?

Comment: @Sampath I don't. sorry.

Comment: It is really disappointing.It is better if you can mention that on your repo. One question: I need to use `Gauge chart with Ionic 3` app.If I use your module for that will it work `AOT` use case? I have seen this video where it has been created very recently using your module (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSg8n5_uaWs) . I have this kind of requirement https://github.com/Bigous/ng2-highcharts/issues/78. So would you recommend that repo(https://github.com/Bigous/ng2-highcharts) for that?

Comment: have not tested with ionic.

Comment: IMO, a not maintained library shouldn't be the accepted question

Comment: Angular2-highcharts does *not* work with IVY (Angular 9) and is no longer maintained. We used it for 2 years, but have to switch libraries now.

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is a bit stale, but is one of the first hits for angular2+highcharts queries... It's pretty simple and straight forward to get highcharts working. Here is a plunker example, https://plnkr.co/edit/8ccBrP?p=preview.

Here is the main logic:

```
import {
    Component,
    ElementRef,
    AfterViewInit,
    OnDestroy,
    ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';

const Highcharts = require('highcharts/highcharts.src');
import 'highcharts/adapters/standalone-framework.src';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <div #chart></div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('chart') public chartEl: ElementRef;

  private _chart: any;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    let opts: any = {
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [
                7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2,
                26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6
            ]
        }]
    };

    if (this.chartEl && this.chartEl.nativeElement) {
        opts.chart = {
            type: 'line',
            renderTo: this.chartEl.nativeElement
        };

        this._chart = new Highcharts.Chart(opts);
    }
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this._chart.destroy();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful. Simple and straightforward.

Comment: @crh225 Looks like the zone.js version was not compatible with the later version of angular. Here is an updated plunkr (no code changes on my end): https://plnkr.co/edit/8ccBrP?p=preview

Comment: @roto the events are not working with this implemention.

Answer (score 10):

I think that you could try ng2-highchart (https://github.com/Bigous/ng2-highcharts).

See this project for a sample of use: https://github.com/Bigous/angular2-seed-ng2-highcharts.

- How to set it up in SystemJS configuration: https://github.com/Bigous/angular2-seed-ng2-highcharts/blob/master/src/index.html#L43 and https://github.com/Bigous/angular2-seed-ng2-highcharts/blob/master/tools/config.ts#L108

  ```
  <script>
    System.config({
      map: {
        'ng2-highchart': 'node_modules/ng2-highchart'
      },
      (...)
    });
  </script>
  ```
- How to configure it within a component: https://github.com/Bigous/angular2-seed-ng2-highcharts/blob/master/src/home/components/home.ts#L10

  ```
  import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
  import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
  import {Ng2Highcharts, Ng2Highmaps, Ng2Highstocks} from 'ng2-highcharts/ng2-highcharts';

  @Component({
    selector: 'home',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './home.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.css'],
    directives: [Ng2Highcharts, Ng2Highmaps, Ng2Highstocks]
  })
  export class HomeCmp implements OnInit {
    (...)
  }
  ```
- How to use it within a component template: https://github.com/Bigous/angular2-seed-ng2-highcharts/blob/master/src/home/components/home.html#L9

  ```
  <div [ng2-highcharts]="chartOptions" class="graph"></div>
  ```

Comment: your link has been broken

Answer (score 5):

To install this library, install peer dependencies first:

```
$ npm install --save highcharts@^4.2.1
```

Also, make sure you install the typings for Highcharts:

```
$ npm install @types/highcharts --save
```

Then, install this library running:

```
$ npm install --save ng2-highcharts
```

> app.module

```
import { Ng2HighchartsModule } from 'ng2-highcharts';

add Ng2HighchartsModule to @NgModule => imports
```

> angular cli Add this JS files in script

```
"../node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js",
    "../node_modules/highcharts/highcharts-more.js", 
    "../node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"
```

> component file

```
import { Ng2Highcharts } from 'ng2-highcharts';


private chartData = {
chart: {
  type: 'column'
},
xAxis: {
  categories: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
},
series: [
  {
    name: 'NC',
    data: [7057, 6858, 6643, 6570, 6115, 107, 31, 635, 203, 2, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'OK',
    data: [54047, 52484, 50591, 49479, 46677, 33, 156, 947, 408, 6, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'KO',
    data: [11388, 11115, 10742, 10757, 10290, 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'VALID',
    data: [8836, 8509, 8255, 7760, 7621, 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'CHECK',
    data: [115, 162, 150, 187, 172, 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'COR',
    data: [12566, 12116, 11446, 10749, 10439, 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34, 2]
  }
]};
```

> And the HTML

```
<div [ng2-highcharts]="chartData"></div>
```

Comment: In my opinion, this should be the best solution to approach.

Comment: I got an error on html.

Can't bind to 'ng2-highcharts' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: i think you haven't made the changes in module

Answer (score 4):

Added this to package.json:

```
"angular2-highcharts": "^0.3.3",
"highcharts": "^5.0.0",
```

Added this on main.module.ts file:

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
```

Added this on main.module.ts in @NgModule imports section

```
imports: [ // import Angular's modules    
    ChartModule
],
```

Added this in vendor.ts file:

```
//Angular2-highcharts
import { Highcharts } from 'angular2-highcharts';
require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/solid-gauge')(Highcharts);
```

Added this on the chart.component.ts file

```
import { Highcharts } from 'angular2-highcharts';
```

declare this on inside the chart.component class code:

```
options: HighchartsOptions;
chartData: any = [];
```

Add this code in the method that binds the data to the chart:

```
this.options = {
      chart: { type: 'spline' },
      title : { text : 'chart' },
      xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime'
      },
      series: [{
        name: "name",
        data: this.chartData
      }]
    };
```

Added this on the chart.component.html page:

```
<div>
      <chart [options]="options"></chart>
    </div>
```

Comment: `import { Highcharts } from 'angular2-highcharts';` => Module has no exported member 'Highcharts'

Answer (score 4):

I didn't tested yet but HighCharts has its official [Angular library](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) which seems to be actively maintained.

Answer (score 3):

PrimeNG charts can be an alternative. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach without need of 3rd party library.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'my-chart',
    template: `<div style="width:60%" id="container"></div>`
})
export class AppComponent { 
    private data = [
            {
                name: 'USA',
                data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                    1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                    27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                    26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                    24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                    22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                    10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104]
            }, 
            {
                name: 'USSR/Russia',
                data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                    5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                    4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                    15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                    33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                    35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                    21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
            }];

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.renderChart();
    }

    renderChart(){
        jQuery('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: thebulletin.metapress.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>' +
                             '<br/>warheads in {point.x}'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    pointStart: 1940,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: this.data
        });
    }
}
```

And put down this to index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Or try this module http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular2-highcharts, if you need to handle on point select event.

Answer (score 3):

As of October 2018:

[angular-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts) is the new kid on the block and has overtaken [angular2-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts) in popularity.

angular-highcharts is an Angular directive based implementation of highcharts and ATTOW requires Angular 7 (which was released very recently)

I have no affiliation to either library.

Answer (score 1):

With usage of official highcharts module only (w/o angular2-highcharts and other and even @types/highcharts)

npm install --save-dev highcharts

```
import * as HC from 'highcharts';
...
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
  let chartOptions = {
  ...
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'chartPanel', // need to have div #chartPanel in template
      ...
    }
  }
  this.chartInstance = new HC.Chart(chartOptions);
}
```

this.chartInstance will have all highcharts methods like addSeries, reflow, redraw etc.