# Trouble with integrating ng2-highcharts

Tags: highcharts, angular

I am trying to use ng2-highcharts in  my application. But after importing the necessary classes using the statement

```
import {Ng2Highcharts, Ng2Highmaps, Ng2Highstocks} from 'ng2-highcharts/ng2-highcharts';**
```

if I try to specify these classes in the array of directives in my component (`directives: [Ng2Highcharts]`), I am getting the following error in my console.

```
[TypeError: require is not a function][1]
```

My System.config looks as follows
[System.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnlTr.png)

Can someone tell me what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define 'ng2-highchart' within your SystemJS configuration:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    map: {
     'ng2-highchart': 'node_modules/ng2-highchart'
    },
    (...)
  });
</script>
```

See this question for more details:

- [How to use highcharts with angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719921/how-to-use-highcharts-with-angular-2/35719957#35719957)

Comment: I have defined it in my SystemJS configuration but the problem still exists. You can see my SystemJs configuration if you click on the System.config link in my question.

Comment: I think that you don't need the 'ng2-highchart' entry in the `packages` block. The one in the `map` one is enough...

Comment: I am afraid not. Leaving that gives the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". It doesn't even find the ng2-highcharts.js file if I remove the entry in the packages block.

Comment: It seems that `../../node_modules/ng2-highcharts/` isn't the right path. Could you check this? You can't define ng2-highcharts elements in packages since they aren't systemjs-compliant but commonjs. Perhaps you could change the format to `commonjs` instead. But I think that there is a problem on your path in the `path` block...

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. But isn't that the path to the ng2-highcharts folder in node_modules ? If so, based on my project structure, I believe `../../node_modules/ng2-highcharts/` is the path.

Comment: Yes it's this path ;-) Did you try with commonjs value as format within the packages block?

Comment: I am sorry. But how exactly should I change and try ? I am new to development in JS and I am not sure what exactly it means. Thanks a lot for your help till now :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my candlestick sample... see if this helps.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {JSONP_PROVIDERS, Jsonp} from '@angular/http';
import { CHART_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2-highcharts';


@Component({
    selector: 'high-chart',
    directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [JSONP_PROVIDERS],
    template: `
    <h2> This is HighChart CandleStick component </h2>

        <chart type="StockChart" [options]="options3"></chart>
    `
})

export class HighChartsComponent {

    options3: Object;

    constructor(jsonp : Jsonp) {

        jsonp.request('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?a=e&filename=aapl-ohlc.json&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK').subscribe(res => {
            this.options3 = {
                title : { text : 'CandleSticks' },
                rangeSelector : {
                    selected : 1
                },
                series : [{
                    type : 'candlestick',
                    name : 'CandleSticks',
                    data : res.json(),
                    dataGrouping : {
                    units : [
                        [
                            'week', // unit name
                            [1] // allowed multiples
                        ], [
                            'month',
                            [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    }
                }]
            };

        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove format: 'register' from you packages. This will help it detect the right format. Or you can add the format as follows:

```
System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
           "node_modules/ng2-highcharts": {
                format: 'cjs',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
              }
        },
        map: {
            "ng2-highcharts/ng2-highcharts" : "node_modules/ng2-highcharts/ng2-highcharts"
        },
        paths: {
            "ng2-highcharts/ng2-highcharts" : "node_modules/ng2-highcharts/ng2-highcharts"
          }
      });
```