# How to convert this require statement to import using systemjs / es6?

Tags: highcharts, typescript, angular, systemjs, jspm

so I am using angular2 / TypeScript and trying to convert this call which works fine today by the way:

```
window['Highmaps'] = require('highcharts/modules/map')(Highcharts);
```

to es6

something to the sorts of:

```
import * as Ng2Highcharts from 'highcharts/modules/map';
Ng2Highcharts(Highcharts)
```

but no luck as the former works but the es6 version does not.
this is the project by the way: https://github.com/Bigous/ng2-highcharts

and I have to convert it since I am trying to move from commonjs to systemjs,

thanks for any help,

Sean.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Answer (score 2):

```
window['Highmaps'] = require('highcharts/modules/map')(Highcharts);
```

The value of the require is immediately applied as a function. This typically implies there's a default export that's being used.

Try

```
import Ng2Highcharts from 'highcharts/modules/map';
Ng2Highcharts(Highcharts)
```

Comment: when doing this I get TypeError: x[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a constructor :(

Answer (score 1):

To be able to import like that you need to create an entry in the `system.config.js` file or just `System.config({...})`, however you are doing the config.

---

One entry goes in the `map` and one in `packages` like this

```ts
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'highcharts':                 'path/to/highcharts-directory'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'highcharts/modules/map':                 { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
```

And you're good to go....   Hope it works.

Comment: if I do this way I get back an object in my:import * as Ng2Highcharts from 'highcharts/modules/map';  so where do I pass in Ng2Highcharts(Highcharts) to? as Ng2Highcharts is now an object, not a function? tx

Comment: `import * as Ng2Highcharts` means you've imported an objecte consisting of everything exported in `'highcharts/modules/map'` file. So if that file contains a function named `Ng2Highcharts`, `Ng2Highcharts.Ng2Highcharts(Highcharts);` should do

Comment: or you can just import that function `import {Ng2Highcharts} from 'highcharts/modules/map'`, and use it like `Ng2Highcharts(Highcharts)`.

Comment: {Ng2Highcharts} from 'highcharts/modules/map' worked, and Ng2Highcharts(Highcharts) worked as well, but unfortunately when I used it it gave an odd error: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: x[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a constructor
  ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:  which I have no idea why, as it works fine if I change back to commonjs... weird!

Comment: excuse me, I don't know how `Ng2Highcharts` work, so I can't help much with usage. But have you seen [How to use highcharts with angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719921/how-to-use-highcharts-with-angular-2) ?

Comment: what is `Ng2Highcharts(Highcharts)` supposed to do ?